# How to create a column with the value of a column from the previous row?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset and I would like to create a new column where the value of this new column is equal to the value of the previous row.

What I have:

| col_a | col_b |
| --- | --- |
| x | 189 |
| y | 33 |
| z | 0 |
| k | 837 |
| H | 33 |

What I am looking for:

| col_a | col_b | new_col |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x | 189 | 189 |
| y | 33 | 189 |
| z | 0 | 33 |
| k | 837 | 0 |
| H | 86 | 837 |

It is something very similar to what `df = df.fillna(method='ffill')` does, but it is not working for what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use shift in creating a col_c and then ffill to update the missing values from col_b

```
df['col_c'] = df['col_b'].shift(1)
df.fillna(method='ffill', axis=1)
```

```
    col_a   col_b   col_c
0       x   189     189
1       y   33      189
2       z   0        33
3       k   837       0
4       H   33      837
```